# determining of packages are loaded in compiled form, R 2.13.0

Tags: r, compiler-construction

We have just installed R version 2.13.0 as an RSERVE and it seems to be working well.  We want to try and take advantage of pre-compiling loaded packages using the bytecode compiler.  We *think* we got it configured correctly, but wanted to verify.

Is there a command we can issue that shows which packages are loaded in bytecode compiled form?

Answer (score 0):

By default none are, so you would have to tell us more about what you did in order for us to have a chance to assess whether you were in fact successful.